# Where to store code that doesn't belong to a model or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a couple of utility methods that don't belong to a class or model yet.

Where is a good place to keeps this code? And how do I call it from with a model?

```
def get_api
 Clickatell::API.authenticate(ENV['AP_ID'], ENV['PASSWORD'])
end

def send_sms(from, message)
 begin
  api = get_api
  api.send_message(from, message)
 rescue Exception => exc
  logger.error(message + " " + "Message for the log file #{exc.message}")
  render :text => "#{exc.message}", :status => 200
 end 
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could implement the module under "lib" directory or under lib's sub-directory.

In application.rb，if you modify autoload_paths to:

```
 config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

It will be automatically loaded.

If you don't want to change the config, you can require the the file at the beginning of your model file.

```
require "relative_path_under_lib"
```

Answer (score 4):

Put it in a class, put this class in the /lib folder. You can then either add it to the autoload path like this:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

or simply require it where needed.

One alternate approach could also be to write a model if the functionality you wrap is very model like (is part of the business logic). A model does not necessarily have to be related to a database table. (Though I would then use a subfolder below /models for such functionality)

This for simple small things you add on the run. If you have larger things to add, then maybe a plugin or engine would be an option.